# IF Statement in Visualforce Title

Tags: visualforce

Based on the outcome I want to show different "titles" in the visualforce pageBlockSection.

This is what the result should look like:

"You have an overall of XXX Customers"
or
"You have in this area XXX Customers"

So far I have:

```
"{!if(myInput == '1000',warehouses.size  , warehouses.size)}"
```

I can't figure out how to combine my variables (*warehouse.size*) and plain text. (*You have .... customers*)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple merge statements in Visualforce:

```
{!...}{!...}{!...}
```

Or, you can use TEXT to convert a number to text:

```
{!TEXT(IF(...,...,...))}
```

Or, you can use apex:outputText:

```
<apex:facet name="header">
<apex:outputText value="You have {0} customers.">
  <apex:param value="{!if(...,...,...)}" />
</apex:outputText>
</apex:facet>
```

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox, thank you for your reply. However I am not sure how any of this can help me. What I am look for is a working version of this:

{!if(myInput == '1000',  'You have an overall of' warehouses.size 'customers' , 'You have' warehouses.size 'customers in the area')}

Comment: @JanTonnet `<apex:outputText value="{!IF(myInput='1000','You have an overall of {0} customers','You have {0} customers in the area.')}><apex:param value="{!warehouses.size}" /></apex:outputText>` should work (using the apex:facet in my answer), or the TEXT formula would work, too.

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox thanks.This does work! What would it look like if I have more than 1 variable?

Let's say:

<apex:outputText value="{!IF(myInput='1000','You have an overall of {0} customers in the last {1} month','You have {0} customers in the area from the last {1} month.')}"><apex:param value="{!warehouses.size}" /></apex:outputText>

 Do I add another param value? What would the syntax be?

Comment: @JanTonnet Yes, add more apex:param, one for each placeholder, up to 10 ( `{0}` through `{9}`).

Comment: Thanks man! That was really helpful.